# CSS: border-color using rgba in IE7-8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Most of the resources I could find on this related to gradients. This is NOT about gradients.

Has anyone discovered a way to enable `rgba` for use in a `border-color` property with IE7 and/or IE8?

Example:

```
p {
    background-color: #D00;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.75);
}
```

Comment: I would simply add rgb() fallback for IE7.

Comment: Thanks, @Cristy. I should have mentioned that I do have that, for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have full control of the HTML you want to apply this to, it is possible to achieve using a wrapper that has a second background colour (which acts as the borders)

```
<style type="text/css">
.p-wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    padding: 1px;
}
.p-wrapper p {
    background-color: #D00;
}
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
.p-wrapper {
    background: transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000);
    zoom: 1;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

And then as the HTML:

```
<div class="p-wrapper">
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Although if this is really just for 1px, I'd do as Cristy suggests and just specify a RGB fallback